# Can't run mongod command after got pymongo installed from pip

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm running a virtualenv on osx 10.7.4, and I was trying to install MongoDB for python, which is version 2.7.3.

I just installed it from pip, and am trying to see what happens if I run mongod command, but it turns out I can't run the command.

Below is what happened in my terminal, could anyone give a hand here about what could be wrong?

```
(test1)Dus-MacBook-Air:~ mepine$ pip install pymongo
Downloading/unpacking pymongo
  Downloading pymongo-2.2.1.tar.gz (230Kb): 230Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymongo

Installing collected packages: pymongo
  Running setup.py install for pymongo
    building 'bson._cbson' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibson -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c bson/_cbsonmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibson -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c bson/time64.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/time64.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibson -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c bson/buffer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibson -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c bson/encoding_helpers.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbsonmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/time64.o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/encoding_helpers.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/_cbson.so
    building 'pymongo._cmessage' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibson -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c pymongo/_cmessagemodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/pymongo/_cmessagemodule.o
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibson -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c bson/buffer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.2/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/pymongo/_cmessagemodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/bson/buffer.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/pymongo/_cmessage.so

Successfully installed pymongo
Cleaning up...
(test1)Dus-MacBook-Air:~ mepine$ mongod
-bash: mongod: command not found
```

Thanks guys!!

Comment: You are running this while in your virtualenv. Are you sure its not modifying your paths and making mongod not avail. Did mongod use to work outside of your virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you're confusing the python mongo driver with the mongo server itself.

Did you install mongodb (mongod, mongo, etc.), or just pymongo?

There's a homebrew package for mongodb, just in case you want an easy way to install it--or you can download it directly from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads.

Comment: Yeah I just installed pymongo. I'll install mongodb itself but don't know whether the order matters.

Comment: I installed mongodb itself and it turns out to work perfectly. Thanks Wes!